# Xamarin forms - MVVM observable collection always null

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have the strangest issue with an observable collection. I set my collection with some dummy data and it loads on the content page as expected however when I attempt to get the data from the data context its always null.

I debugged the code in the ViewModel and I can see the collection as null. Its clearly not null because I populates on the form.

Is there something im missing here !

```
private ObservableCollection<Company> _CompanyCollection;
public ObservableCollection<Company> CompanyCollection
{
   get { return _CompanyCollection; }
   set
   {
      if (value != null)
      {
        _CompanyCollection = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }
}
```

Loading data

```
public void LoadTestCompanies()
{
  CompanyCollection = new ObservableCollection<Company>()
  {
    new Company() { Name="The Suit Lounge"},
    new Company() { Name="The Suit Lounge"},
    new Company() { Name="The Suit Lounge"}
  };
}
```

Calling Viewmodel from event in page.cs

```
CompaniesVM viewModel = (CompaniesVM)BindingContext;
var results = viewModel.CompanyCollection.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchBar.Text.ToLower()));
```

This is the code behind

```
public Companies ()
{
InitializeComponent ();
    BindingContext = new CompaniesVM(this.Navigation);           
}
```

ViewModel calls loatTestCompanies

```
   public CompaniesVM(INavigation navigation)
    {

        // Navigation 
        Navigation = navigation;

        LoadTestCompanies();

    }
```

Ive tried many other ways of initialising the collection and use .Add(object> but nothing seems to be working.

Any ideas would be great.

Thank you

Comment: Have you already used `LoadTestCompanies` function in your code?

Comment: That's indeed weird. Could you show the code behind of your XAML? Specially where you create the instance of the ViewModel and set the BindingContext...

Comment: Are you missing call viewModel.LoadTestCompanies()?

Comment: Try using OnPropertyChanged("CompanyCollection");
Also make sure that your model class implements INofityPropertyChanged.

If you still have issues, please post the code where you bind your ObservableCollection to the view.

Comment: Ive updated the original comment above. I only call the loadTestCompanie on setting the datacontext so its only called the once 

This is the oddest issue ive ever come across

Comment: Only way I can achieve what I need is to put the code behind the xaml file, not ideal but works. 

This issue is very wierd

Answer (score 1):

Two advises that may solve your problem:

#### 1

Use a self-declared readonly property when referring to collections:

```
public ObservableCollection<Company> CompanyCollection { get; }
```

#### 2

This change will force you to create the instance of `CompanyCollection` directly in the constructor:

```
public CompaniesVM(INavigation navigation)
{
    Navigation = navigation;
    CompanyCollection = new ObservableCollection<Company>();
    LoadTestCompanies();
}
```

And then...:

```
public void LoadTestCompanies()
{
    CompanyCollection.AddRange(new[]
        {
            new Company() { Name="The Suit Lounge"},
            new Company() { Name="The Suit Lounge"},
            new Company() { Name="The Suit Lounge"}
        });
}
```

I believe that changing the reference itself for bound properties implies in `ViewModel` using an object instance and the `View` using another one. So the view 'stops' to listen to VM changes for that property.

I've never got into the deep of `ItemsSource`s `Views` implementations, but I guess they kind of observe the items when binding collections - or the collection instance's properties in some cases - when getting changes notification.

With this changes, I guess your code should work fine.

Hope it helps.